How can I disable the GNOME Tour system-wide?
I'm creating purpose-built operating system images based on Fedora Silverblue and want to disable the tour that GNOME Shell pops up on first login. How can I do this?
Other answers I've seen have suggesting just removing the gnome-tour package, but I can't get this to work in my build environment. Is there any other way of doing this?

Yes, there is. You can set the dconf key /org/gnome/shell/welcome-dialog-last-shown-version to your GNOME Shell version, surrounded by single quotes. For example, this will disable GNOME Tour system-wide on an RPM system like Fedora:
# cat > /etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-disable-gnome-tour <<EOF
[org/gnome/shell]
welcome-dialog-last-shown-version='$(rpm -qv gnome-shell | cut -d- -f3)'
EOF

You'll need to run that in a root shell, or use sudo tee instead of cat to get around permission errors.
